# django -'function' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, django

I'm using this code to convert my image to jpeg and I have the following error

> 'function' object has no attribute 'read'

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_filename)
thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=generate_filename, editable=False, blank=True, null=True)

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

    if self.image:
        import os
        from PIL import Image 
        im = Image.open(os.path.join(generate_filename))
        im.thumbnail(im.size)
        im.save(outfile, "JPEG", quality=100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `generate_filename` is a function. `Image.open` expects a string or a file object as first parameter. You get this error because PIL tries to call the `read` method that is present on file objects on a object that is not a file object.

Try this:

```
im = Image.open(os.path.join(generate_filename()))
```

Also, `im.thumbnail(im.size)` does not seem very useful as you are creating a thumbnail the size of the original image.